# Using vc++ Dll in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-c++, dll

I am working on a c# crawler/Poster project, it crawls wordpress blogs, sites, using WebClient to download content.

Wordpress sites use a bug or i don't know, of WebClient, for some reason it does not accept all cookies, from wordpress blogs, it may be a measure to stop auto bots, spammers.

So decided to use Sockets, but seems sockets also has a few problems, it sometimes does not return full response, so not reliable, but i found a good working code in VC++, i am trying to use it in C#, but i dont know vc++ at all.

Here is the [code](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8cde981fb07c02a3&sc=documents&uc=1&id=8CDE981FB07C02A3%21122#)

How do i create a dll of the above code?

I have created a simple dll project using vc++ but unable include the above code in the project.

Updated Link to [Code](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8cde981fb07c02a3&sc=documents&uc=1&id=8CDE981FB07C02A3!122#)

Comment: The link to your code takes me to a site asking me for my credit card. Maybe Dropbox or Microsoft Skydrive would be an easier way to share.

Comment: scroll down on the right side it says "Slow Download", it will download for free.

Comment: sorry for the trouble, 1 min i am putting a Skydrive link, sorry again

Comment: I got it.  Don't bother.  I'll write up some comments shortly.

Comment: Could you show the code you have tried with `WebClient` and provide an example of a website for which it doesn't work?

Comment: actually i had posted a thread for the same here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402267/httpwebrequest-with-multiple-set-cookie

Comment: Please post your code here on Stack Overflow, not on an external website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use platform invokes, creating a declaration for each function you need. Here's an example of importing the `MessageBox` WinAPI function (note that this is not the same as the MessageBox class in .NET!)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have downloaded your code, I can say this...

Even if we got this code to compile, we still have to do the normal heavy lifting of interop between C++ and C#.  And the code isn't even ready for that.  The http_download.h file is a big set of inline classes.   And the instructions for making C++ Code invokable from C# is to long to list here.  You would basically have to get this code to compile as a DLL.  Then from the DLL either export a set of "C" functions that invoke your C++ to do what you want.  Or convert these C++ classes into COM objects with a type library.

But let's analyze what you are really trying to do:

> You want to crawl web pages, but WebClient doesn't work.

So I think the real question you want to ask:

> Why doesn't WordPress accept my cookies with WebClient?

And I really don't know the answer, because you haven't shared your WebClient code or elaborated what you think may be the issue.  But I bet it's an easily solved problem.

I'm certain WebClient will be 10x easier to use than than some C++ code hacked up as one .h file that doesn't look very pretty.  And it will be 100x time easier than trying to put together a HTTP library using pure sockets (which is what WebClient is, but it supports all the features you need, but haven't realized yet).

Sorry if I'm curt.  I'm trying to encourage you to think about this a better way than doing it the hard way.

Answer (score -1):

Create a class library by using the C++ code and add it as a reference to your C# project.

Comment: as i already said, dont know much about vc++, please tell me how and what should id do to use the code, the original link where i downloaded it is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/asynchttp.aspx

Comment: @downvoter : Could you please leave a reason for the downvote?